# CSS auto expand width for a table

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website, and I need the layout looks like this:

```
+---+--------------+
|#  |              |
|n  | #page        |
|a  | table.basic  |
|i  |              |
|g  |              |
|a  |              |
|t  |              |
|i  |              |
|o  +--------------+
|n  | #pagination  |
+---+--------------+
```

Here is the HTML & CSS:

```css
 #navigation {
   float: left;
   width: 150px; /* Fixed size*/
   min-height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 2em;
 }
 #page {
   float: left;
   width: auto; /* Auto size. Something need to be changed here.*/
   padding-left: 2em;
   vertical-align: top;
 }
 #pagination {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   position: relative;
   clear: both;
   padding: 0.5em;
   text-align: center;
 }
 table.basic tr th,
 table.basic tr td {
   /* or change something here*/
   border: 2px solid #000000;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 1em 0;
   padding: 1em;
 }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">Show navigation</div>
<div id="page">
  <table class="basic">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Long long thing</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="pagination">Show pagination</div>
</div>
```

The page content with the table needs to automatically expand, so it doesn't float under the navigation bar. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `width: calc(100% - 150px)`? Or `calc(100% - 150px - 2em - 2em)`?

Comment: mind to write correctly your css comments (i edited it already ) :)

Answer (score 0):

`#page` doesn't need to float, but it needs to deal with the floatting navigation.

Classic and easy  way to do that is to use overflow:hidden;. This change the block formating context.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

```css
div {/*demo purpose*/ border:solid;}
#navigation {
   float: left;
   width: 150px; /* Fixed size*/
   min-height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 2em;
 }
 #page {
   overflow:hidden;
   padding-left: 2em;
   vertical-align: top;
 }
 #pagination {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   position: relative;
   clear: both;
   padding: 0.5em;
   text-align: center;
 }
 table.basic tr th,
 table.basic tr td {
   /* or change something here*/
   border: 2px solid #000000;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 1em 0;
   padding: 1em;
 }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">Show navigation</div>
<div id="page">
  <table class="basic">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Long long thing</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="pagination">Show pagination</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really close to what I need. But instead of expand the width, it breaks the string in the table to fit the screen.

Comment: I need the page to expand in width so the row stays one line, any idea?

Comment: @NobleDinasaur nop, no idea of what you mean ?? one row, what where, when i see a 2 col layout ??